# Почему слово проиСходить нужно писать через "с"?

Tags: глаголы

Почему слово проиСходить нужно писать через "с"?
Ведь глагол совершенного вида пишется через "з": произойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего эти формы глагола - супплетивные, они от разных корней происходят - "идти" и "ходить" - с некоторыми историческими изменениями фонетики. Поэтому проверять написание одной формы через другую вообще нельзя, вопрос "почему" не должен стоять в принципе.

Что же касается самих глаголов, то в их морфологическое членение таково: 
Про-ис-ходить и про-изо-йти. Две приставки и корень.

**"Ис"** и **"Изо"** это две разные формы приставки. Приставки **"исо"** вообще не существует. Поэтому в тех случаях, когда требуется **"изо"**, вариантов просто нет.
А вот правописание формы **"из"**/**"ис"** определяется правилом для приставок на **-з/-с**. Форма **"из"** используется перед звонкими и гласными, **ис** - перед глухими.
Еще раз подчеркну, это правило вообще не применимо к форме **"изо"**. Форма ИЗО вообще довольно редкая, она возникает как правило перед скоплением согласных, но в случае "произойти" её появление предопределяется историческими изменения в фонетике основы "идти". И в этом есть определенная сложность для понимания. Для изучающих русский как иностранный такие вещи лучше принять как есть и просто запомнить, не претендуя на глубокий анализ.

Answer (score 0):

Исходить - избегать и т.п. По общему правилу правописания приставок из(ис), воз(вос) и др. "Как слышится, так и пишется". Перед глухой согласной - С, перед звонкой или гласной - З.